# Table view nil/not updating

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, uitableview

I have a table view with only one cell. When I call a method, I try to refresh it and the text label's text should change. However it does not, it only changes if the view re appears.

I have added `NSLog()` in many places and the correct methods and conditions are called

I have tried a few things:

```
reloadData
setNeedsDisplay
setNeedsLayout
reloadCell
reloadRowsAtIndexPaths: withRowAnimation:
```

But **nothing** has worked, I know it is not a problem with my `UITableViewDataSource` code because it is properly getting called.

This is the most appropriate code I can give you:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    tableView.scrollEnabled = NO;

    UITableViewCell *cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier: @"cell"];

    if (cell) {

        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

        if ([[TravelLogViewController locationArray] count]) {

            NSDictionary *flight = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[[TravelLogViewController locationArray] lastObject], @"name", [[TravelLogViewController dateArray] lastObject], @"date", [[TravelLogViewController milesGainedIndex] lastObject], @"miles", nil];

            cell.detailTextLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];

            cell.textLabel.numberOfLines = 2;
            cell.detailTextLabel.numberOfLines = 2;

            cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Avenir" size: 14.0];
            cell.detailTextLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Avenir" size: 12.0];

            cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

            cell.textLabel.text = [flight objectForKey: @"name"];

            cell.detailTextLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Flight Date: %@, Miles Gained: %.1f", [flight objectForKey: @"date"], [[flight objectForKey: @"miles"] doubleValue]];

            cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0.92 alpha:1];
            //        cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        }
        else {

// This gets called when I want it to, but the textLabel text or detailTextLabel text is not changed


            cell.detailTextLabel.text = nil;
            cell.textLabel.text = nil;
            cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial Rounded MT Bold" size: 18.0];
            cell.textLabel.text = @"\n\n                 No Flights";
        }
    }

    return cell;
}
```

UPDATE:

I am using ARC, and I have found that the table view is nil at the time I try to update the cell, but I have revised my cell and have no clue why!?

I am not nilling or releasing my table view anywhere, it should still be allocated

By the way I have a tab bar controller

UPDATE:

I have started a bounty now, its over a week later and I really feel this question needs some more attention and answers, I have checked my code multiple times and I **cannot** see why the table view is not updating / is `nil`.

UPDATE:

Ok, I have forgot to mention that the user can swipe to delete the cell. When he does, it does not actually **delete** the cell, it just changes its text (that is the part it is not updating). I put logs in `viewDidLoad` and `viewDidAppear` and table view appears to be valid, once the user swipes to delete... here is my code:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {

    TravelLogViewController *travel = [[TravelLogViewController alloc] init];
    [travel manuallyDeleteTopCellData]; // Deletes some data in other view controller and calls the method `proceedWithDeletion`
}
}
- (void)proceedWithDeletion {

// Method is called from another view controller

NSLog(@"%@", mostRecentFlight.description); // NIL HERE

[mostRecentFlight reloadData];
[mostRecentFlight setNeedsDisplay];
[mostRecentFlight setNeedsLayout];

}
```

**TravelLogViewController**

```
- (void)manuallyDeleteTopCell {

[TheMileIndexViewController deductDesiredMilesToIndex: [[milesGainedIndex lastObject] floatValue]];

[locationArray removeLastObject];

[milesGainedIndex removeLastObject];

[dateArray removeLastObject];

MenuMileIndexViewController *menu = [[MenuMileIndexViewController alloc] init];
[menu proceedWithDeletion];

}
```

So to sum up, one the view loads/appears, the table view is valid. When the user swipes to delete, it does not **actually** delete the row it just calls another view controller called `TravelLogViewController` method called `manuallyDeleteTopCellData` where it deletes some data, that method then calls another method in my original view controller called `proceedWithDeletion` where it is supposed to reload the table view, but doesn't (the problem). The reason for this is because in `proceedWithDeletion` the table view is nil, but why!?

Comment: And how should we find a problem without code?

Comment: @Sharanya code has been posted

Comment: cell.detailTextLabel.text = @"";
 cell.textLabel.text = @"";

Comment: show code that calls reloadData. Have you checked the table it is called on is not nil?

Comment: @Eiko I put at if statement and logged it and the table was nil, i will double check my code to see why

Comment: In the nib..... do you mean the UITableView data source method code?

Comment: Sorry, how many UITableViews are there in the view controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code could be the source of your problem:

```
MenuMileIndexViewController *menu = [[MenuMileIndexViewController alloc] init];
[menu proceedWithDeletion];
```

You're creating a brand new `MenuMileIndexViewController`, not accessing the already existing instance, which is what I presume you want to do. This new instance won't have access to the original table view stored in `mostRecentFlight`. Inside `-manuallyDeleteTopCell`, you'll need a reference to the calling `MenuMileIndexViewController` instance.

It might be as simple as passing `self` to `-manuallyDeleteTopCellData` and using that variable to subsequently call `-proceedWithDeletion` on. For example:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
        TravelLogViewController *travel = [[TravelLogViewController alloc] init];
        [travel manuallyDeleteTopCellData:self];
    }
}

- (void)manuallyDeleteTopCell:(id)sender {
    [TheMileIndexViewController deductDesiredMilesToIndex: [[milesGainedIndex lastObject] floatValue]];
    [locationArray removeLastObject];
    [milesGainedIndex removeLastObject];
    [dateArray removeLastObject];
    // MenuMileIndexViewController *menu = [[MenuMileIndexViewController alloc] init];
    [sender proceedWithDeletion];
}
```

Comment: Oh ok, makes a lot of sense, didn't notice that, nice method.....Would it be better to create a delegate?

Comment: You could go with a delegate, but in practice I've never seen one controller act as the delegate of another controller. That's not to say you can't do it. Another option is passing in a completion block to `-manuallyDeleteTopCellData`. Yet another option is using notifications.

Answer (score 3):

It's a blind shot without any code, but, if you using `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier`, it might cause the problem. If you have one cell, you can create it every time in your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` instead of re-using already created. Won't effect performance with such tiny table

Comment: Oh wow, surprised I missed that! That is true, however it does not work, I will post some code

Comment: Why would using `dequeueResuableCellWithIdentifier` cause a problem? That's only triggered if the cell is scrolled completely out of the window.

Answer (score 2):

I can pretty much confirm that the problem is not in the areas you're looking or describing.

I have created a sample project from scratch, very minimally just putting a `UITableView` and a `UIButton` that triggers a `[table reloadData]` and flips a boolean value:

```
BOOL toggle = NO;

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 1;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier: @"cell"];

    if (cell) {

        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

        if (toggle )
        {
            NSDictionary *flight = @{@"name" : @"Bob",
                                 @"date" : @"Yesterday",
                                 @"miles" : @"3" };

            cell.textLabel.text = [flight objectForKey: @"name"];
            cell.textLabel.numberOfLines = 2;

            cell.detailTextLabel.numberOfLines = 2;
            cell.detailTextLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
            cell.detailTextLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Flight Date: %@, Miles Gained: %.1f", [flight objectForKey: @"date"], [[flight objectForKey: @"miles"] doubleValue]];

        } else {

            cell.textLabel.text = @"blank label";
            cell.detailTextLabel.text = @"blank detail";
        }
    }
    return cell;
}

- (IBAction)toggleValue:(id)sender
{
    toggle = !toggle;
    NSLog( @"toggle is now %@", (toggle) ? @"YES" : @"NO" );

    [tv reloadData];
}
```

By referencing the boolean value in `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` and using the code you provided, you can see that the row(s) do in fact update as expected when `[table reloadData]` is called.

You can download the sample project here (35KB): http://rdas.me/SampleProject.zip

I hope that this help you. If nothing else it should help you isolate where the problem may in fact reside.

Good luck!

Comment: Um, that isn't just updated, that completely reframes the problem: "Table view not updating IN EDIT MODE" :) — if you're not sure where the problem is in the first place, next time please try and provide as much context as possible, it might lead to quicker resolution!

Comment: Haha yeah... I did not realize this may be the problem until why

Answer (score 1):

In your implementation of `manuallyDeleteTopCell` in `TravelLogViewController` you instantiate a new `MenuMileIndexViewController` at this point:

```
MenuMileIndexViewController *menu = [[MenuMileIndexViewController alloc] init];
[menu proceedWithDeletion];
```

This is a different controller and is neither properly initialized nor responsible for the view on the screen. In particular, it does not have the same `mostRecentFlight` property. In order for the `TravelLogViewController` to call your original controller, you need to pass it as a parameter to `manuallyDeleteTopCell` and call that one back, e.g. as follows

```
- (void)manuallyDeleteTopCell:(MenuMileIndexViewController *)origin {
    [TheMileIndexViewController deductDesiredMilesToIndex: [[milesGainedIndex lastObject] floatValue]];

    [locationArray removeLastObject];
    [milesGainedIndex removeLastObject];
    [dateArray removeLastObject];

    [origin proceedWithDeletion];
}
```

And rewrite the calling code as follows:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
        TravelLogViewController *travel = [[TravelLogViewController alloc] init];
        [travel manuallyDeleteTopCellData:self];
}
```

Former suggestions:

1. Make sure that you have set the outlet properly in the Interface Builder. You say in a comment that you did this, but at another point you say that you are using a tab bar controller. Make sure you are setting the outlet on a regular view controller (i.e., a subclass of `UIViewController`) that is currently visible and contained in the `viewControllers` property of the `UITabBarController` instance you are using. **Do not subclass `UITabBarController`** (see the [Apple documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UITabBarController_Class/Reference/Reference.html) which explicitly prohibits it). **[CHECKED]**
2. Implement the `viewDidLoad` method of the regular view controller and `NSLog` the `self.tableView` property to verify it is non-`nil` at the time this method is called. **[CHECKED]**
3. Write a `@synthesize mostRecentFlight = _mostRecentFlight;` statement in the `@implementation` of `TravelLogViewController` and set a breakpoint on the property in the `@interface`. Alternatively, manually implement the `setMostRecentFlight:` method for the `mostRecentFlight` property and set a breakpoint inside this method. This breakpoint will trigger if the setter is called which will help you find the time the property is set to `nil`.
4. Assuming the property is non-nil in the `viewDidLoad` method in step 2, look at the **address** of the object (the beginning of the description which says `(UITableView *) $1 = 0xXXXXXXXX` with `0xXXXXXXXX` being the address). Set a breakpoint where you want to use the object later in your code (when the property is nil). Type at the debugger `po 0xXXXXXXXX` (with the appropriate address from above). What is the response you get?

Answer (score 0):

I usually use this code:

```
[_myTable beginUpdates];

[... update my cell, adding / removing / changing them ...];

[_myTable endUpdates];
```

It works on my projects since version 5.0.

Answer (score 0):

According to your comment, the `tableView` variable you called `reloadData` on was `nil`.

Common reasons for this are missing links to the IBOutlet in case of using a nib, weak ivars with ARC, or masking the ivar with a local variable with the same name.

Comment: It is probably a weak ivar, I will check it out when I get home

Comment: The outlet has been set, the ivar is strong, and there is no local instance variable masking it

Comment: Hmm this seems get steamy after double checking i am just really stuck.:::

Comment: Is it possible that you instantiate your view controller multiple times, i.e. once in code, once in nib - and are working on the wrong one?

Answer (score 0):

I can't find anything wrong in your code. However, please make sure you set your table view data source and delegate like (should be set somewhere in viewDidLoad/viewDidAppear/viewWillAppear):

```
[tableView setDelegate:self];
[tableView setDataSource:self];
```

After this, make sure you return the number of rows you  need to display from the delegate method:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    return [yourDataSource count];
}
```

best of luck!

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to notice. if you are working with storyboard you don't need to alloc your cell. This code is enough:

`- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView )tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath)indexPath
   {`

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView 
  dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"PlayerCell"];
Player *player = [self.players objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.textLabel.text = player.name;
cell.detailTextLabel.text = player.game;
return cell;
```

}